# Wordpress - Using functions outside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I using the following code for an external php file which is being executed through curl:

```
    <?php
include ('wp-config.php'); //Not sure how to do it.

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) { 
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];
$url = 'http://www.example.com/RequestDetails?UserId='.$username.'&pass='.$password;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $resultauth=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    /*----Working fine till now*/

if ($results == 'authenticated user'){
$auth_options = get_option( 'user_options' );
$auth_options['user'][$username] = array( 'verified'=>'pendingverified', 'timestamp'=> current_time( 'mysql' ) );
}
?>
```

The `$auth_options['user'][$username]` is not working and I guess it is because this file is not linked to wordpress.

Does anybody know why that happens? Did I forget to include something?

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to consider a more secure form of authenticating a user. Passing a plain text password over HTTP sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Hey @NathanDawson That was just an example. But anyway, for information, How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include wp-load.php

`include ( 'wp-load.php' );`

Comment: Right. Looking at my code snippet, I encountered strange behaviour - nothing output after this line. So I added `ob_end_flush();` three times before the latter code. I don't know who locks the buffer, but it can be helpful for someone.